# Performing (sync or async) network request in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, authentication, request, async

Following a question on the mailing list about what is the best way to perform network requests in PyQGIS both blocking and non-blocking and with or without support for authentication (QGIS' authcfg)?

See: https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2019-November/044363.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Nyall's answer:

- **QGIS 3.4**:

  - **Blocking**:

    - **With auth**: python nam (but be aware that it CAN and DOES crash
      crashes if used on the main thread)
    - **Without auth**: python nam (but be aware that it CAN and DOES crash
      crashes if used on the main thread)
  - **Non-blocking**:

    - **With auth**: python nam
    - **Without auth**: QgsNetworkContentFetcher
- **QGIS 3.6 - 3.8**:

  - **Blocking**:

    - **With auth**: QgsBlockingNetworkRequest
    - **Without auth**: QgsBlockingNetworkRequest
  - **Non-blocking**:

    - **With auth**: python nam
    - **Without auth**: QgsNetworkContentFetcher
- **QGIS 3.10 and above**:

  - **Blocking**:

    - **With auth**: QgsBlockingNetworkRequest
    - **Without auth**: QgsBlockingNetworkRequest
  - **Non-blocking**:

    - **With auth**: QgsNetworkContentFetcher
    - **Without auth**: QgsNetworkContentFetcher

The Python nam refers to a Python implementation of a network access manager supporting authcfg. Can be found [here](https://github.com/opengisch/qgis-swiss-locator/blob/master/swiss_locator/core/network_access_manager.py) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some more ways if needed.

There is a QGIS Processing algorithm `native:filedownloader` which can be called using `processing.run`.

There is also QgsFileDownloader : https://qgis.org/api/classQgsFileDownloader.html